# Twitter API Showing "No value for full_text" error?

Tags: java, android, twitter

So I'm using Twitter's API in my android application but the search query doesn't seem to work no matter what.

My vision:
To show users all the tweets containing the phrase I mention (i.e Android).

Here's my code:

```
public class TweetsFragment extends Fragment implements InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.LoadMoreListener {

    private RecyclerView listView;
    private TweetAdapter tweetAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    private Activity mAct;
    private RelativeLayout ll;

    String searchValue;
    String latesttweetid;
    String perpage = "25";

    Boolean isLoading = true;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ll = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        searchValue =  this.getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
        listView = ll.findViewById(R.id.list);

        tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        tweetAdapter = new TweetAdapter(getContext(), tweets, this);
        tweetAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        listView.setAdapter(tweetAdapter);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = getActivity();
        refreshItems();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            if (!isLoading){
                refreshItems();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mAct, getString(R.string.already_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void refreshItems(){
        isLoading = true;
        latesttweetid = null;

        tweets.clear();
        tweetAdapter.setHasMore(true);
        tweetAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        new SearchTweetsTask().execute(searchValue);
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<Tweet> result) {
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            tweets.addAll(result);
        }

        if (result.size() == 0)
            tweetAdapter.setHasMore(false);
        tweetAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoreRequested() {
        if (!isLoading){
            new SearchTweetsTask().execute(searchValue);
        }
    }

    //Connect to twitter api and get values.
    private class SearchTweetsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Tweet>>{

        private String URL_VALUE;
        private final String URL_BASE = "https://api.twitter.com";
        private final String URL_TIMELINE = URL_BASE + "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?" +
                "count="+perpage+"&" +
                "tweet_mode=extended&" +
                "exclude_replies=true&" +
                "include_rts=1&" +
                "screen_name=";
        private final String URL_SEARCH = URL_BASE + "/1.1/search/tweets.json?count="+perpage+"&q=";
        private final String URL_PARAM = "&max_id=";
        private final String URL_AUTH = URL_BASE + "/oauth2/token";

        private final String CONSUMER_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_consumer_key);
        private final String CONSUMER_SECRET = getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_consumer_secret_key);

        private String authenticateApp(){

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuilder reply = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(URL_AUTH);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                // Encoding keys
                String credentials = CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET;
                String authorisation = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                String parameter = "grant_type=client_credentials";

                // Sending credentials
                connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authorisation);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                connection.connect();

                // sending parameters to method
                os = connection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(parameter.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                reply = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){            
                    reply.append(line); 
                }

                Log.d("Post response", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
                Log.d("Json response - tokenk", reply.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("INFO", "Exception: " + e.toString());

            }finally{
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            if (reply == null) return null;
            return reply.toString();
        }


        //Showing the progressdialog while loading data in background
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();

            isLoading = true;
        }



        //Get the latest tweets from the timeline of the user
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Tweet> doInBackground(String... param) {

            String searchValue = param[0];
            Boolean search = false;
            if (searchValue.startsWith("?")){
                URL_VALUE = URL_SEARCH;
                try {
                    searchValue = URLEncoder.encode(searchValue.substring(1), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.printStackTrace(e);
                }
                search = true;
            } else {
                URL_VALUE = URL_TIMELINE;
            }
            ArrayList<Tweet> result = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                URL url;
                if (null != latesttweetid && !latesttweetid.equals("")) {
                    Long fromid = Long.parseLong(latesttweetid) - 1;
                    url = new URL(URL_VALUE + searchValue + URL_PARAM + Long.toString(fromid));
                }else {
                    url = new URL(URL_VALUE + searchValue);
                }
                Log.v("INFO", "Requesting: " + url.toString());
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                String jsonString = authenticateApp();
                JSONObject jsonAccess = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                String tokenHolder = jsonAccess.getString("token_type") + " " + 
                        jsonAccess.getString("access_token");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", tokenHolder);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.connect();

                // retrieve tweets from api
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuilder reply = new StringBuilder();

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){            
                    reply.append(line); 
                }

                Log.d("GET response", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
                Log.d("JSON response", reply.toString());

                JSONArray jsonArray;
                JSONObject jsonObject;

                if (search){
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(reply.toString());
                    jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("statuses");
                } else {    
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(reply.toString());
                }

                result = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    Tweet tweet = new Tweet();

                    tweet.setname(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"));
                    tweet.setusername(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name"));
                    tweet.seturlProfileImage(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("profile_image_url").replace("_normal", ""));
                    tweet.setmessage(jsonObject.getString("full_text"));
                    tweet.setRetweetCount(jsonObject.getInt("retweet_count"));
                    tweet.setData(jsonObject.getString("created_at"));
                    tweet.setTweetId(jsonObject.getString("id"));

                    try {
                        if (jsonObject.has("extended_entities")){
                            String mediaurl = ((JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject("extended_entities").getJSONArray("media").get(0)).getString("media_url");
                            if (((JSONObject) jsonObject.getJSONObject("extended_entities").getJSONArray("media").get(0)).getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("photo"))
                                tweet.setImageUrl(mediaurl);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.printStackTrace(e);
                    }


                    latesttweetid = jsonObject.getString("id");

                    result.add(i, tweet);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.printStackTrace(e);
                Log.e("INFO", "Exception: GET " + e.toString());

            }finally {
                if(connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        //Populate listview with tweets after background task has been completed. If results are empty
        //then show error toast.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Tweet> result){
            isLoading = false;
            if (null != result) {
                updateList(result);
            } else {
                Helper.noConnection(mAct);
                tweetAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_EMPTY);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh_menu, menu);

        ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, mAct);
    }


}
```

Here's the error log:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for full_text
W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392) 
W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553) 
W/System.err: at providers.twitter.ui.TweetsFragment$SearchTweetsTask.doInBackground(TweetsFragment.java:284) 
W/System.err: at providers.twitter.ui.TweetsFragment$SearchTweetsTask.doInBackground(TweetsFragment.java:128) 
W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Line #284:

```
tweet.setmessage(jsonObject.getString("full_text"));
```

Line #128:

```
private class SearchTweetsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Tweet>>{
```

Changing "full_text" to "text" seems to work but it cuts out most of the characters so need help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use something like stetho to log the actual JSON response from the twitter API? Also, do yourself a HUGE favor and look at volley or retrofit. You just create an object class that models the JSON response and it works like magic without having to do all the work deserializing JSON. https://github.com/square/retrofit

Comment: I would guess that "full_text" is nested inside the jsonObject in a way where you need to deserialize further to get access to it. You need to look at the raw JSON.

Comment: Another option, add breakpoints just before the crash, run in debug mode, and look at the structure of jsonObject. Paste it here.